# Why am I getting a false traceback in Python?

Tags: python, exception, traceback

I got an error message that didn't make sense in a script that scrapes websites for Ethereum prices.

This is where the exception was raised:

```
        # part of a loop
        ....
        element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
        data = element.text.split('\n')
        symbol, price = tuple(data[-2].split(' '))
        assert symbol == 'Ξ'
        total_price += float(price)
    price_list.append((total_price, dict_with_data))

# in top namespace
price_list.sort() #<-- the acual line that raised an exception
```

This is the false traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line 142, in <module>
    assert symbol == 'Ξ'
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

The error message is correct and I already fixed it, but it says the error happaned in the line `assert symbol == 'Ξ'` which is obviously wrong because it happened in the line `price_list.sort()`. Why is this traceback giving me false information?

Comment: is the loop inside the sort function? if so, that is why.

Comment: I don't think you understand Python.

Comment: Did you change the source file *after* you ran the code? Because that is the most common way this might happen. There are probably others.

Comment: a trace will put the error at the line that fails   ... and the line that called that line   ...and the line that called that line    ... and the line that called that line    ...and so on that isnt just python that is how stacks work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes that must have caused it. So the Python parser only memorizes line numbers and then reads the line after an exception has been raised? What would happen if the file has fewer lines than the error line?

Comment: if the error was only on the offending line, it wouldnt be "tracing" anything

Comment: @NathanToulbert Yes exactly. And as you can clearly see there is only one traceback line. The coulprit has been found. Thanks for trying. And no, the error is ALWAYS traced even if it happens on just one line.

Comment: @NathanToulbert I think the OP understands that, the problem is that the traceback is pointing to *the wrong line*. This can happen if you change the source file (and other edge cases)

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga Look at the comments in the first code block of OP. does it not look like  `price_list.sort()`  is calling the code above it?  ergo, the stack trace is correct?

Comment: @NathanToulbert no, it isn't. `list.sort` is a built-in method of list objects, the traceback wouldn't go in there in CPython. Admittedly, you would have to be familiar with Python for this to be obvious. More importantly, `assert symbol == 'Ξ'` would never throw the actual error that's being thrown. I understand why it might look this way, but upon careful consideration, it's clearly pointing to the wrong line

Comment: I understand. I was just going off of what I could see. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: Admittedly, I should have seen straight away that it was just the Python list.sort method; it was just an oversight on my part... my bad